# Drill down of DashBoards using BIRT

Tags: spagobi

drilldown of charts can be done by considering the parent chart and child chart by relating them with some common parameter. But how can we drilldown the dashboard, as it consists  of different charts in a single document?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to create associations between different charts. When you click the [association Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XykoW.png) (on the top right corner), you are able to connect different columns with each other. 
After you confirm this association you can drill down through both charts with one click.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Can we drill down the dashboards using SpagoBI tool?  I got drill down of individual charts.But what if we have 4 different charts in a single dashboard, can we drill down using SpagoBI?